# Input Yes/Y and No/n vb.Net console

Tags: vb.net, console

What is the best way to Y/Yes and N/No?

```
Private Function ExitGame() As Boolean

    Dim input As String = ""

    Do
        If input <> "yes" And input <> "no" Then
            Console.WriteLine("Would you like to play again ('yes' or 'no')?")
            input = Console.ReadLine().ToLower()
        ElseIf input <> "y" And input <> "no" Then
            Console.WriteLine("Would you like to play again ('yes' or 'no')?")
            input = Console.ReadLine().ToLower()
        End If
    Loop
    Return input = "yes"

End Function
```

Comment: Maybe cut it short: `Console.WriteLine("Would you like to play again? ([Y]es)") dim userChoice = Console.ReadKey().Key return userChoice <> ConsoleKey.Y` (no *loops*)

Comment: You have the condition backwards. Your method is named `ExitGame`, so should return `True` if the user wants to exit. You ask them if they want to play again and return `True` if the respond "yes". You exit the game if they say they want to play again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Private Function ExitGame() As Boolean
    Dim input As String = String.Empty

    Do While input = String.Empty
        Console.WriteLine("Would you like to play again ('yes[y]' or 'no[n]')?")
        input =  Console.ReadLine().ToLower()
        Dim r As Regex = New Regex("[y|n]")
        If Not r.IsMatch(input) Then input = String.Empty
    Loop
    Return input = "y"
End Function
```

For further details, please see:

[StartsWith](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.startswith?view=net-5.0)

[Substring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=net-5.0)

[Regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=net-5.0)

Comment: Doesn't work its looping in "Would you like to play again ('yes[y]' or 'no[n]" when i input y/Yes

Comment: Thank you. Imported so file for Regex. Then it works

Answer (score 3):

I would implement it like this:

```vb
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Do
            Console.WriteLine("play, play, play")
        Loop Until ExitGame()
    End Sub

    Private Function ExitGame() As Boolean
        Do
            Console.Write("Would you like to play again ([Y]es/[N]o)? ")

            Dim key = Console.ReadKey().Key

            Console.WriteLine()

            Select Case key
                Case ConsoleKey.Y
                    'Play again and do not exit game.
                    Return False
                Case ConsoleKey.N
                    'Exit game without playing again.
                    Return True
            End Select
        Loop
    End Function

End Module
```

Note that I have the condition the right way around, i.e. if the want to play again then I do not exit the game and vice versa.

Note also that, by using `ReadKey`, the user doesn't have to press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key and they can't mistakenly waste their time typing "yes" when only "y" is required and they can't type something ambiguous like "yikes". Don't make the user do more than is necessary.

Comment: Hi, I tried your solution but it didn't work for me. it didn't loop the game when the user press y nothing happens then when the user press Enter the console closes.

Comment: It worked for me exactly as you would expect, i.e. if you pressed Y then it played again, if you pressed N then it exited and if you pressed anything else it prompted you again. That means that the code I provided is correct and you just did it wrong. If you don't show us what you did, i.e. update your question with your new code, then we can't tell you what you did wrong. Did you take into account the reversal of the Boolean condition, as I have pointed out twice?